# How to generate an empty UUID in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, uuid

Currently, I use the "UUID package" (UUID 2.2.2) to generate a random UUID.

```
Uuid().v4().toString();   // -> 11c43ee8-b9d3-4e51-b73f-bd9dda66e29c
```

Some of our data have a reference to an empty guid (C#) instead of null. Is there a way to generate this empty guid or do I need to hardcode it somewhere for comparison reasons?

I expect this output for an empty UUID:

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the static Uuid class from that package and get this constant value.

`Uuid.NAMESPACE_NIL`

e.g.

```
const empty = Uuid.NAMESPACE_NIL;
```